# How to hide div when scrolling down and then show scroll up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to make the case for showing and hiding menu like the picture.

You can see in the following image there is a tree part. First part when you open the page the right bottom side menu will still showing.

When you scroll down then the menu will fadeIn, and when you sroll up then the menu will fadeOut.

The facebook and tumblr doing like this. I want to learn how can they do this. Anyone can tell me little example or something.

I created this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/raEzJL)** from codepen.io but it is only header think and also there is a problem when scroll up.

[image]

```
var previousScroll = 0, // previous scroll position
        menuOffset = 54, // height of menu (once scroll passed it, menu is hidden)
        detachPoint = 650, // point of detach (after scroll passed it, menu is fixed)
        hideShowOffset = 6; // scrolling value after which triggers hide/show menu
    // on scroll hide/show menu
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      if (!$('nav').hasClass('expanded')) {
        var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop(), // gets current scroll position
            scrollDifference = Math.abs(currentScroll - previousScroll); // calculates how fast user is scrolling
        // if scrolled past menu
        if (currentScroll > menuOffset) {
          // if scrolled past detach point add class to fix menu
          if (currentScroll > detachPoint) {
            if (!$('nav').hasClass('detached'))
              $('nav').addClass('detached');
          }
          // if scrolling faster than hideShowOffset hide/show menu
          if (scrollDifference >= hideShowOffset) {
            if (currentScroll > previousScroll) {
              // scrolling down; hide menu
              if (!$('nav').hasClass('invisible'))
                $('nav').addClass('invisible');
            } else {
              // scrolling up; show menu
              if ($('nav').hasClass('invisible'))
                $('nav').removeClass('invisible');
            }
          }
        } else {
          // only remove “detached” class if user is at the top of document (menu jump fix)
          if (currentScroll <= 0){
            $('nav').removeClass();
          }
        }
        // if user is at the bottom of document show menu
        if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
          $('nav').removeClass('invisible');
        }
        // replace previous scroll position with new one
        previousScroll = currentScroll;
      }
    })
    // shows/hides navigation’s popover if class "expanded"
    $('nav').on('click touchstart', function(event) {
      showHideNav();
      event.preventDefault();
    })
    // clicking anywhere inside navigation or heading won’t close navigation’s popover
    $('#navigation').on('click touchstart', function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
    })
    // checks if navigation’s popover is shown
    function showHideNav() {
      if ($('nav').hasClass('expanded')) {
        hideNav();
      } else {
        showNav();
      }
    }
    // shows the navigation’s popover
    function showNav() {
      $('nav').removeClass('invisible').addClass('expanded');
      $('#container').addClass('blurred');
      window.setTimeout(function(){$('body').addClass('no_scroll');}, 200); // Firefox hack. Hides scrollbar as soon as menu animation is done
      $('#navigation a').attr('tabindex', ''); // links inside navigation should be TAB selectable
    }
    // hides the navigation’s popover
    function hideNav() {
      $('#container').removeClass('blurred');
      window.setTimeout(function(){$('body').removeClass();}, 10); // allow animations to start before removing class (Firefox)
      $('nav').removeClass('expanded');
      $('#navigation a').attr('tabindex', '-1'); // links inside hidden navigation should not be TAB selectable
      $('.icon').blur(); // deselect icon when navigation is hidden
    }
    // keyboard shortcuts
    $('body').keydown(function(e) {
      // menu accessible via TAB as well
      if ($("nav .icon").is(":focus")) {
        // if ENTER/SPACE show/hide menu
        if (e.keyCode === 13 || e.keyCode === 32) {
          showHideNav();
          e.preventDefault();
        }
      }
      // if ESC show/hide menu
      if (e.keyCode === 27 || e.keyCode === 77) {
        showHideNav();
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    })
```

Comment: You want something like this one [Back To Top](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Auto-Hiding-Navigation-Menu-showup/).

Comment: @Suprabhat yes you are right. I found this plugin but there is something went wrong when i change the position top to bottom

Comment: Please share what kind of changes you made as that can be be easily sorted out.

Comment: The @waltur-buerk s answer is what i want i am trying to make that code. Can you tell me if you have a time how can i add a transition effect in this code like when scroll down then the red div slideDown (hide) When scroll up then SlideUp (show) [DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/bNPoNG)

Comment: Ok i get it what you are asking for. Initially you want the menu to be shown on footer, as user scroll it should fade out , and fade in when user reachs bottom on the page. Let c what i can do.

Comment: @Suprabhat yes you understood what i want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74930/discussion-between-innovation-and-suprabhat).

Comment: Check out my edit in my answer at the end. I added a little fuddle for your convenience. https://jsfiddle.net/d00h1zmn/1/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might be looking for something like this? Whenever you scroll, it checks how far you've scrolled and in what direction from your previous scroll position.

```
var previousScroll = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (scroll > previousScroll){
       // downscroll code
   } else {
      // upscroll code
   }
   previousScroll = scroll;
});
```

Here's a little complimentary JSFuddle with some modification and live action application of that script: https://jsfiddle.net/d00h1zmn/4/

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I did it like this [DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/bNPoNG)

Comment: You have a little problem in that demo. The animations keep stacking up if you quickly scroll up, down, up, down. I edited my fiddle now so it slides instead of fades, and my solution also solves the animation queue problem.

Comment: oh i see the it now thank you your answer it what i want but my DEMO is a little good (think). But it has a problem i need to use it like your DEMO. Thanks again.

Comment: replaced previousScroll = Math.max(0,scroll); Mac safari issue fixed

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `onscroll` attribute in HTML. For example, when you scroll down, element looks like this: `<div id="header" class="sdown_concealed"></div>`. Meanwhile, scroll up looks like this: `<div id="header" class="sup_visible"></div>`. It might be harder than using Jquery, but people who only want to use Javascript and no libraries can use a technique like this: `<div id="header" class="unchanged" onscroll="scrollDown();"></div>`. After scroll: `<div id="header" class="sdown_concealed" onscroll="scrollUp(); this.onscroll = scrollDown;"></div>`. It's a less simple solution, but I found it very helpful as I do not use Javascript Libraries such as Jquery (I should, though).

Comment: I need to add an update, guys. This solution was way harder than I thought. I have no way of telling whether the user scrolled up or down with `onscroll`. You'll have to use Waltur Buerk's solution. It works brilliantly.